# Reverse a 3d array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering if there is a way to reverse a 3d numpy array? Like in 1d case we can go from [1 2 3] to [3 2 1]. Is there something similar for 3d?

Thanks

Comment: First you need to define what it means to "reverse" a 3D array.

Comment: what do you expect a reversed 3d array to look like ?

Comment: `my_array[::-1]` will reverse any array ... but i doubt thats what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean reverse it along an particular axis?

For example, if we have a color image of the size `height x width x 3` where the last axis is red, green, blue (RGB) pixels, and we want to convert it to blue, green, red (BGR):

```
image_bgr = image[:, :, ::-1]
```

If you'd prefer, you can even write that as:

```
image_bgr = image[..., ::-1]
```

As a more complete example, consider this:

```
import numpy as np

# Some data...
x = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape(5, 4, 3)

print x[0,0,:]

# Reverse the last axis
y = x[:, :, ::-1]

print y[0,0,:]
```

In general, though, you can use this to reverse any particular axis.  For example, you could just as easily have done:

```
y = x[:, ::-1, :]
```

To reverse the second axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer helped get the correct results! :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can use the `flip` function from the `numpy` library, whose parm `axis` indicates the index along which the matrix needs to be reversed.

```
np.flip(x, axis=2)
```

this is the equivalent of

```
x[:, :, ::-1]
```